# Laravel redirect after update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have an update action in a controller called AssetController.

At the end of the action I do `return \Redirect::route('asset.edit', array($id));`

In my Routes I have `Route::resource('asset', 'AssetController');`

When I post to the update action it takes me to "/asset/8" (8 being the id of that asset record). I want it to go to "/asset/8/edit" -- in other words simply returning the user to the edit form that they just submitted for update.

I also tried `return \Redirect::back()` but that also sends to "/asset/8" -- even thought the URL of the page they just submitted was "/asset/8/edit".

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple. Just use this line of code:

```
return redirect(route('asset.edit', array('id' => $id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
return redirect("asset/".$id);
```

Or

```
return redirect()->route('asset.edit', compact('id'));
```

Or

```
return redirect()->route('asset.edit', ['id' => $id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a key

```
return \Redirect::route('asset.edit', array('id' => $id));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-named-routes

Comment: Thanks, I wish you were right, but this does not change a thing. Laravel interprets a single parameter passed as the id. (I tried your suggestion just to be sure, but no go.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My return was within a DB::transaction() and therefore it was ignoring it.

My original return statement works fine once I put it outside the DB::transaction() function.

Answer (score 0):

Register your tout like this:

```
Route::resource('asset', 'AssetController', ['names' => [ 'edit' => 'asset.edit ]]);
```

then use your redirect:

```
\Redirect::route('asset.edit', array($id));
```

Comment: That's not necessary -- it works just fine as it was in my code. My error was that the redirect was happening inside a db:transaction() function. Once I put it outside the function, it worked without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to add an element input :

```html
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

on your edit template OR edit blade

Comment: That is not necessary. Again, once I removed the return statement from the DB:transaction() it worked as expected.